# Does HTTP authentication can be handled by JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, selenium, authentication, browser, automation

I'm trying to automate HTTP basic authentication remotely using selenium. 
I don't want use a solution like: user:password@host .
I'm using *ExecuteScript* method which execute java script remotely via the webdriver.

Is there any way doing it with JS ? i thought about KEYPRESS event but seems like it's not working on the authentication windows.

This is a sample site:
http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth

[image]

Comment: I don't think Javascript has any access to this dialog.

Comment: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/34